# Should I get Revival for answering my own question?

Tags: discussion, badges, revival-badge

I asked a [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/68244/847). No-one answered. 5 years later, I answered it. Today, the answer got an upvote that qualified it for the Revival badge. But can one really Revive one's own question? I am not sure that was the intention.

Comment: Why not? It's not like you can vote for your answer

Comment: I clicked the "revival-badge" tag and it only had 15 Q's...Second from the top was the duplicate target.

Answer (score 7):

Generally speaking, the badges you can't earn with a self-answer are the ones depending partially on actions you fully control. Examples:

- Depending on accepting the answer:

  - Enlightened
  - Guru
  - Tenacious / Unsung Hero
  - Populist
- Depending on editing the question - if you have <2k reputation, that's not automatic:

  - Explainer / Refiner / Illuminator

Revival does not depend on such actions, so it's rather logical self-answers also qualify for it.

([Scholar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/10/scholar) seems to be an exception, here are a couple of users who have it from a self-answer: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7241226/jelle), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10257075/john-mcdowel), [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12892895/behrad-nafar). Since it's counted as a *question* badge, that might make sense ...)

Comment: It makes sense for Scholar to be awarded for self-answers. The question must be 48+ hours old to accept a self-answer, which helps prevent gaming, and I think it's good to award if someone doesn't immediately self-answer but discovers the solution on their own later.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog I agree. I'm just including it as the exception that proves the rule :)

Answer (score 6):

I think self-answering is a behavior to be encouraged even, and especially, when a question has gone unanswered for a long time.

If long unanswered questions are not revived by anyone providing an answer then they remain unanswered. I think a belated useful (upvoted) self-answer should be rewarded by the same badge that would be issued if any other user had provided it.